# AJAX call to PHP help in parsing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, cordova

I'm new to AJAX.The situation is such. I am writing a HTML app that will be embedded inside a mobile app (using PhoneGap).  My requirement is that the html page will poll a php script that will return some information. I have been trying to call it. but I dont know how to parse the information, since it is not executing the callBack function or the success function.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://crosswave.zetalight.com/radio.php?callback=?',
success: function (json) {
alert("Success")
}
// console.log("Polling Radio");
,
dataType: "jsonp",
jsonpCallback: 'readData',
context: this,
type: "GET",
crossDomain: true,
error: function AjaxFailed(result) {
alert("hello1");
alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
},
//modify the value to change the timer currently its 5000 = 5seconds
complete: setTimeout(function (result) {
poll()
}, 10000),
timeout: 5000
})
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoudln't append '?callback=?' to 'url' prop. Also in usual case it is unnecessary to specify 'jsonpCallback' prop. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://crosswave.zetalight.com/radio.php',
success: function (json) {
console.log("response: "+json);
},
dataType: "jsonp",
jsonp: 'callback',
context: this,
type: "GET",
crossDomain: true,
...
```

**UPDATE:**
The URL in your example isn't intended for JSONP use. See here:
http://crosswave.zetalight.com/radio.php?callback=callback. 
The response isn't wrapped with JS function callback() call. So it doesn't comply JSONP.

Comment: I did try that. it went off to the error block, error 200 and statustext load

Comment: Sorry. I forgot adding 'jsonp' prop

Comment: Didn't change anything. sorry :(

Comment: Hi,  turns out that i was doing the right thing, and that the radio.php site had some problems. Thanks hindmost